# SonarQube Azure AD Integration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, sonarqube

I have a Sonarqube hosted VM in Azure, I tried to integrate with AAD, created the App Registration and given all the details like client ID, Tenant ID, etc. Unfortunately the Sonarqube is hosted without SSL, So i changed the URL from General Settings. But still i'm getting the error **"You're not authorized to access this page. Please contact the administrator."**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the limitations for Redirect URIs for Azure AD App Registrations listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url
Also make sure the app registration is done correctly. You can follow the steps mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2

In case the details shared above doesn't help in fixing the authorization error, we would like to understand the actual error code AAD is throwing to SonarCube along with the correlationID and timestamp so that we can check some backend logs based on those.